# Unexpected output while decoding the buffer array of type Uint8Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

The following javascript code tries to decode the buffer array of type **Uint8Array**. But the value retrieved for first item of the array is 0 instead of 10.

```
    console.log(registers)
    // Prints [ <Buffer 00 0a>, <Buffer 00 00> ]

    var uint8 = new Uint8Array(registers);
    console.log(uint8);
    // Prints Uint8Array { '0': 0, '1': 0 }

    The expected output : Uint8Array { '0': 10, '1': 0 }
```

Comment: Have you made sure the byte-order is the same?

Comment: @K3N. Yes. readUInt16BE resolved the issue. Thank you.